# How is referencing working in Java?

Tags: java, memory, reference

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * } 
 */

          ListNode newNode = null;
          ListNode nxt = head.next;
          head.next = newNode;
          newNode = head;
          head = nxt;
```

Here is what I visualize when I see this:

Say I have a structure

where `------->` means pointing to (as in memory)

```
head ------->  1->2->3->4->5->6
```

Then this means

```
ListNode nxt = head.next -------> 2->3->4->5->6
```

Then when you do:

```
head.next = newNode
head -------> 1->NULL
```

Then shouldn't `nxt` become?

```
nxt ------->  NULL
```

Since you changed what `nxt` is pointing to?

Comment: But you didn't change what `nxt` is pointing to.

Comment: `nxt` doesn't point to `head.next`. `head.next` and `nxt` are separate references that to point to the same object. Changing one doesn't affect the other. Btw, why is `newNode == NULL`?

Comment: To express it another way - `=` assigns a reference; it doesn't modify the object that's referenced.

Comment: A simpler version if this would be say, `int x=5;` and `int y=x` then you do `x=x+5`, you can check that `y` is still equal to `5`

Answer (score 2):

But you didn't change where `nxt` is pointing to.

```
ListNode nxt = head.next
```

This makes `nxt` point to the same thing as `head.next`, which in this case is the 2.

```
head.next = newNode
```

This changes `head.next`.  It changes nothing else; `nxt` remains as it was, and continues to point to the 2.

Comment: Then how come if I do something like: `head.next.next = null`, it will change the whole structure? Ie from any reference now, I will have something like `1->null` instead of the old `1->2->3`?

Comment: Because in that case, you are changing the object `nxt` is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine:

You have one red arrow that points to a whole bunch of green arrows.

Now get two friends, blindfold them and get them ear pieces (so that nobody can hear what you tell the other one). We're gonna call them "Tim the guy with a head" and "Bob the next guy".

Take Tim's arm and point it to the red arrow.

Now remove Bob's blindfold. Tell him to look at what Tim is pointing to and point to whatever that points to. Since Tim is pointing to the red arrow and the red arrow points to the green arrows, Bob will now point to the green arrows.
Now reapply Bob's blindfold.

Next, it's time to change what the red arrow is pointing to, so turn it by 90°, so now it points to nothing.

And now aks yourself: What is Bob pointing to?

The answer should obviously be that Bob is still pointing to the green arrows.

If you arrived at the same conclusion: Make sure you understand that this is exactly what happens in the case you described in your question.

If you thought Bob would be pointing at nothing now, I encourage you to just try it out in real life ;)